# Error refreshing state: Failed to read remote state: unexpected EOF - Terraform State on GitLab

Tags: gitlab, terraform, terraform-state

I'm try configuring GitLab to save terraform state.

I set my `main.tf` file as below:

```
terraform {
  backend "http" {
    address                 = "https://<myGitLab>/api/v4/projects/<ID-Project>/terraform/state/<Project-Name>"
    lock_address            = "https://<myGitLab>/api/v4/projects/<ID-Project>/terraform/state/<Project-Name>/lock"
    unlock_address          = "https://<myGitLab>/api/v4/projects/<ID-Project>/terraform/state/<Project-Name>/lock"
    username                = "myuser"
    password                = "<Token-ID>"
    lock_method             = "POST"
    unlock_method           = "DELETE"
    retry_wait_min          = 5
  }
}
```

I can run only the first time, `terraform init`,`terraform plan` and `terrafrom apply`

The state is saved correctly on my GitLab project (under Infrastructure->Terraform).

But it I try to re-run `terraform init` I receive this error:

```
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...
2022/01/28 17:06:24 [DEBUG] GET https://<myGitLab>/api/v4/projects/<ID-Project>/terraform/state/<Project-Name>
Error refreshing state: Failed to read remote state: unexpected EOF
```

Note: my terraform files are not in the main root project, but in a subfolder:
`/<Name-Project>/<terraform-folder>/main.tf`

How can fix my problem?

**UPDATE:**
Now I receive this error when I run `terraform plan`:

```
Error: error loading state: Failed to read remote state: stream error: stream ID 3; INTERNAL_ERROR
```

These are the terraform logs:

```
2022-02-08T10:34:03.690Z [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.1.4
2022-02-08T10:34:03.700Z [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.17.2
2022-02-08T10:34:03.701Z [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"terraform", "plan", "-out=plan.out"}
2022-02-08T10:34:03.701Z [TRACE] Stdout is a terminal of width 120
2022-02-08T10:34:03.704Z [TRACE] Stderr is a terminal of width 120
2022-02-08T10:34:03.704Z [TRACE] Stdin is a terminal
2022-02-08T10:34:03.704Z [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /root/.terraformrc
2022-02-08T10:34:03.705Z [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2022-02-08T10:34:03.706Z [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory terraform.d/plugins
2022-02-08T10:34:03.706Z [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /root/.terraform.d/plugins
2022-02-08T10:34:03.706Z [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /root/.local/share/terraform/plugins
2022-02-08T10:34:03.708Z [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/local/share/terraform/plugins
2022-02-08T10:34:03.710Z [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/terraform/plugins
2022-02-08T10:34:03.711Z [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"plan", "-out=plan.out"}
2022-02-08T10:34:03.717Z [TRACE] Meta.Backend: built configuration for "http" backend with hash value 1000000006
2022-02-08T10:34:03.721Z [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
2022-02-08T10:34:03.721Z [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
2022-02-08T10:34:03.722Z [TRACE] Meta.Backend: working directory was previously initialized for "http" backend
2022-02-08T10:34:03.729Z [TRACE] Meta.Backend: using already-initialized, unchanged "http" backend configuration
2022-02-08T10:34:03.737Z [TRACE] Meta.Backend: instantiated backend of type *http.Backend
2022-02-08T10:34:03.741Z [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: scanning directory .terraform/providers
2022-02-08T10:34:03.743Z [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/tpretz/zabbix v0.15.0 for linux_amd64 at .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/tpretz/zabbix/0.15.0/linux_amd64
2022-02-08T10:34:03.744Z [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: including .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/tpretz/zabbix/0.15.0/linux_amd64 as a candidate package for registry.terraform.io/tpretz/zabbix 0.15.0
2022-02-08T10:34:03.861Z [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2022-02-08T10:34:03.866Z [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/bin"
2022-02-08T10:34:03.867Z [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend *http.Backend does not support operations, so wrapping it in a local backend
2022-02-08T10:34:03.869Z [INFO]  backend/local: starting Plan operation
2022-02-08T10:34:03.871Z [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state manager for workspace "default"
2022-02-08T10:34:03.872Z [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state lock for workspace "default"
2022-02-08T10:34:03.873Z [DEBUG] POST https://<myGitLab>/api/v4/projects/<ID-Project>/terraform/state/<Project-Name>/lock
2022-02-08T10:34:04.127Z [TRACE] backend/local: reading remote state for workspace "default"
2022-02-08T10:34:04.127Z [DEBUG] GET https://<myGitLab>/api/v4/projects/<ID-Project>/terraform/state/<Project-Name>
2022-02-08T10:34:04.475Z [DEBUG] DELETE https://<myGitLab>/api/v4/projects/<ID-Project>/terraform/state/<Project-Name>/lock
```

Comment: Sounds like possibly a permissions issue within gitlab. The Developer role allows read access, but the Maintainer Role is needed to lock, unlock & write to the state file. Can you confirm what role you are using in gitlab?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm owner of the project.